# scrape google rhs result using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to scrape the google search result right hand side data using VBA. I am able to scrape the results but not the exact one what i need. Below is the screen shot where i marked in red color what i need to scrape.

[image]

I am tried with the below code in VBA but there is always run time error. How to parse in to the each part and fetch the value inside the span tag.

VBA:

```
Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText
Set objResultDiv = html.getElementById("rhs_block")
Set objH3 = objResultDiv.getElementsByTagName("div")(7).getElementsByTagName("a")(2).getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerHTML
Cells(2, 2) = objH3
```

For the above code i am getting run time error 91 now. How to fix this and parse to fetch the particular span tag value.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may want to grab then entire body of text and then parse out your specific data point.

Since you didn't post the URL, this is just a guess . . .

```
Sub Test() Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl/analystestimates" ' should work for any URL
    Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

        x = .document.body.innertext
        y = InStr(1, x, "Average Target Price:")
        Z = Mid(x, y, 6)

        Range("A1").Value = Trim(Z)

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```